# SQL query not equal to operator not working, with JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I wonder if someone could help me with an SQL query.

I am trying to display all results except where in Table 2 both the userid column equals 1 and the hidden column equals 1.

I am basically trying to hide results from individual users based on their `id` and the value in the hidden column either `1` or empty.

I have so far managed to make a query that does the opposite and can't figure out how to change it. I have tried adding `!=`, `<>`, `NOT` and a few other things, but nothing is working for me!

Here is the query I am working with.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tl.id, tl.name, tl.locale, uh.hidden 
  FROM theList AS tl 
  LEFT JOIN user_hidden_list AS uh ON uh.est_id = tl.id 
  WHERE uh.userid = '1' AND uh.hidden = '1'");
```

How do I display all results expect those with a `uh.userid = 1` and `uh.hidden = 1`

UPDATE: Tables

Table: `user_hidden_list`

```
 userid | Hidden | est_id
---------------------------
   1    | 1      |   1
   2    | 1      |   1
   1    | 1      |   2
```

Table: `theList`

```
id |    name  | locale
------------------------
 1 |    Jacks   |   LDN
 2 |    MacD's  |   LDN
 3 |    BK      |   LDN
 4 |    Byron   |   LDN
```

So if I am logged in with and `userid` of:

`1` I should see: BK and Byron.

`2` I should see: MacD's, BK and Byron.

`3` (or anything else) I should see: Jacks, MacD's, BK and Byron.

Comment: It should work fine with `!=` or `<>`. Maybe look at [when to use quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)? Probably also want to look at proper escaping / [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Comment: Hint: When you reference a column from an outer-joined table, it turns it into an inner join. You can apply filters in the `ON` portion of your query for your outer-joined table.

Comment: What is the column type for userid and hidden?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I have posted an update to the question with tables and outcome!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added some sample data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly, the table **user_hidden_list** mantains a relation between one user and the users he can't see. So for, example, user with id equal to **1** (matching on column **userid**) can't see users **1** and **2** (matching on column est_id).

So, for a particular user with **ID = X**, we can get the **ID** list of user he can't see like next:

```
SELECT
    est_id
FROM
    user_hidden_list
WHERE
    userid = X AND hidden = 1;
```

Using the previous query, we can get the visible users for user **X** like on next query:

```
SELECT
    tl.id, tl.name, tl.locale
FROM
    theList AS tl
WHERE
    tl.id NOT IN (SELECT est_id
                  FROM user_hidden_list
                  WHERE userid = X AND hidden = 1);
```

I'm sure there will be a better (elegant) way to do this, but i'm just leaving work and my mind is not working nice now.

Comment: Thanks! Managed to get it working with a few tweaks! Switched user_id and est_id.

Comment: Also... user_id should look like userid.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to display all results except where in Table 2 both the userid column equals 1 and the hidden column equals 1.

This does not suggest an outer `join`.  You seem to want:

```
SELECT tl.id, tl.name, tl.locale, uh.hidden 
FROM theList tl JOIN
      user_hidden_list uh
      ON uh.est_id = tl.id 
WHERE NOT (uh.userid = 1 AND uh.hidden = 1);
```

I am guessing that `userid` and `hidden` are numbers of some sort, so  I removed the single quotes.  If they are really strings, then use the single quotes.

This also assumes that these values cannot be `NULL`.  If that is a possibility, then the logic can be adjusted (using the null-safe comparator `<=>`).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately I still can't get it to work! I have added some more details to the question!

Answer (score 0):

Try out this, with even parantheses:

```sql
SELECT tl.id, tl.name, tl.locale, uh.hidden 
FROM theList tl JOIN
      user_hidden_list uh
      ON uh.est_id = tl.id 
WHERE (uh.userid <> 1 AND uh.hidden <> 1);
```